# Return specific class based on url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route

```
Route::get('/mailable/{mail}', [TestController::class, 'mailable'])
->where('mail', '(verification)');
```

Based od `{mail}` from url I want to return specific class from my controller

```
public function mailable($mail)
{
    if ($mail == 'verification') {
        return new Verification();
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this or I need to put thousands of `if` statements.
Or I should use `switch`?

I also tried to concatenate `$mail` with `()` to return class but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can do a lot of syntax based on strings, so if your input name is always gonna be the classname by making the first character upper case. You should be able to do the following.

```
$className = "App\Models\\" . ucfirst($mail);

return new $className();
```

This also requires there is a relation between namespaces, an alternative path to this is to map input to output.

```
protected $classMap = [
    'verification' => Verification::class,
]

return new $this->classMap[$mail]();
```

Thou it can quickly become a slippery slope and maybe it is time to consider if you want to be this generic. That all depends on the use case, i don't think generic class instantiation should be applied everywhere it can.

Comment: Should be `"App\Models\\"` so the double quote isn't escaped.

Comment: Updated with correct namespace string :) was to quick on that one.